# unable to push multiple values/ data to the angular 2-tree

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

i am having a dynamic json data & 3 buttons "feed data" it contains one set of dynamic data and button 2 " feed another data" it contains another set of dynamic data  and button 3 is " Send data" here my issue when ever i press feed data and select option and press send data it is working and after that if i press feed another data and press send data then it is giving error"isSelected is undefined"

error simulation :  feed data --> select option --> send data & press feed another data --> select options --> send data then we are getting error

```
  options = {
    useCheckbox: true
  };
  arrayData;
 nodes;
  data = {
  "info": {
    "laptop": {
    },
    "config": {
      "properties": {
        "ram": {
        },
        "processor": {
        },
        "hdd": {

        }
      }
    },
    "link": {

    },
    "name": {

    },
    "company": {
      "properties": {
        "model": {

        },
        "maker": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "enterprise": {

        }

      }
    }
  }
};

 dataa = {
  "info": {
    "mobile": {
    },
    "config": {
      "properties": {
        "ram": {
        },
        "processor": {
        },
        "storage": {

        }
      }
    },
    "link": {

    },
    "name": {

    },
    "company": {
      "properties": {
        "model": {

        },
        "maker": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "country": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "enterprise": {

        }

      }
    }
  }
};
click(tree:TreeModel)
{  

  this.arrayData= [];
  console.log(tree.activeNodes);
    let result: any = {}; 
     let rs = [];
    // tree.selectedLeafNodeIds = {};
    Object.keys(tree.selectedLeafNodeIds).forEach(x=>{

      let node:TreeNode=tree.getNodeById(x);


      if (node.isSelected)
      {  

        if (node.parent.data.name) //if the node has parent
          {
            rs.push(node.parent.data.name+'.'+node.data.name);
            if (!result[node.parent.data.name]) //If the parent is not in the object
              result[node.parent.data.name] = {} //create
            result[node.parent.data.name][node.data.name] = true;

          }
          else {
            if (!result[node.data.name]) //If the node is not in the object
              result[node.data.name] = {} //create
              rs.push(node.data.name);
          }


      }
  }) 
  this.arrayData = rs;

}


feedData(){
   const results = Object.keys(this.data.info).map(k => ({
  name: k,
  children: this.data.info[k].properties
    ? Object.keys(this.data.info[k].properties).map(kk => ({name: kk}))
    : []
}));

 this.nodes = results; 

}

feedAnother(){
  const results = Object.keys(this.dataa.info).map(k => ({
  name: k,
  children: this.dataa.info[k].properties
    ? Object.keys(this.dataa.info[k].properties).map(kk => ({name: kk}))
    : []
}));

 this.nodes = results;
}
```

when ever i press feed data and press send data then i am able to view the info and lie wise i want to update data i press feed another data then press send data then it needs to get the updated results

below is my stack blitz url  : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zapxko

Comment: There are no buttons (feed data or feed another data) in your example. Just two buttons: Clear Filters and sendData.

Comment: @shhdharmen please check now updated file

Answer (score 0):

You can simply change `nodes` object to update the result.

You need to use [Async Data](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/async-data-1) method to update nodes. Here are the [demo](https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/async-data-1#demo) and [code](https://github.com/500tech/angular-tree-component/blob/master/example/cli/src/app/async/async.component.ts) from Angular Tree's official documentation.

Comment: can u apply in my stackblitz ?

Comment: Angular Tree team has provided very nice documentation and code sample. You would be able achieve the expected functionality by referring the same.

Comment: i am  trying thats i unable to sort it out

Comment: when i checked log for console.log(tree.selectedLeafNodeIds); then i saw it call giving ids with previous data  also suppose if i have 1,2  are past ids and now i have 3,4 instead of 3,4 it is also show1,2,3,4,

Comment: You would need to change your feedData logic, data object structure or even sendData logic. It would require some amount of time to think and redesign the approach. It would be difficult for me to write full code for you. Start writing the code and if stuck, let us know.

Comment: dataobject structure is parent n child structure only so need to change it but logic for  getting data means had to think